# how to disable acceptbutton propery in winform application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on winform application..
In my form I have four textbox and one save button.In first key press i written the code like this:

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
{
    fetchdetails()
}
```

if entered id in textbox 1 and I press enter then work fetchdetails and fill another three textbox .Then am saving this details.
After fetching the details if I entered Enter button,then it will automatically fire save button.So in fetchdetails() I given code like this

```
this.AcceptButton=btnsave
```

now what is happening is: if I type id and click enter then it not filling the data.It directly going to save button event.
So what I can do?

Comment: place the condition in the KeyPress code if the data are valid then call save method otherwise call fetchdetails.

Comment: can you please show your fetch details code

Answer (score 2):

you shoul check textbox have data or not before call `fetchdetails()`

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)13 && textbox.text!=string.Empty)
{
fetchdetails()
}
```

Comment: you should check all four text box for null values

Comment: sir,after fetching details then only i need to get default button as save button..

Comment: second time while cliking enter button it directly going to save button click event,,not taking fetch details

Comment: write the fetching details() in the save button itself. if the data is present then you can save the data.

Comment: @Anant Dabhi: see, that text box for fetching details may have value, but the corresponding details may not be fetched from the database or the data may not present in database in such case you should check for all the textbo

Answer (score 1):

```
//Initially in the form
string lastFetchedId = string.Empty;

//KeyDown code
//Remove AcceptButton, if string is being edited etc. Anything other than enter
if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Enter) this.AcceptButton = null;
else
{
    //If something changed
    if (lastFetchedId != textBox.Text)
    {
       //Have Fetch return a true or false, after filling data in the textboxes
       if (fetchdetails(textBox.Text))
       {
         lastFetchedId = textBox.Text;
         this.AcceptButton = btnSave;
       }
    }
}
```